# How to check Not Null for all the attributes of a Model in a Collection in java using Optional?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Lets say there is a `List<Student>`. Each Student have two properties name and Id. I need to check each one of the Student in the list and check each of the two properties. if Both properties and the student object itself are not null then print that student. All using java 8 Optional.

Comment: Optional is not the right tool to do that. A Stream, with null checks inside a lambda passed to filter() or forEach(), is the right one. Also, you should at least try something before asking.

Comment: *The intent of Java when releasing Optional was to use it as a return type* , don't put it at places where it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I am certainly sure there is no need of `Optional` since its usage is to handle `null` values through filtering and mapping and/or offer an alternative value if `null` occurs.

**Stream API solution:**

Here the usage of [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) would be more suitable:

```
students.stream()                                              // Stream<Student>
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)                              // With no null Students
        .filter(s -> s.getId() != null && s.getName() != null) // With no null parameters
        .forEach(System.out::println);                         // Printed out
```

Try the code on the following input:

```
List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(    // only students with id: 1, 2, 4, 6
        new Student(1, "a"),               // ... pass the streaming above
        null,
        new Student(2, "b"),
        new Student(3, null),
        new Student(4, "d"),
        new Student(null, "e"),
        new Student(6, "f"));
```

**Optional example with the null-object pattern:**

Optional would be more suitable in case you want to for example underthrow a null-object (read more about the [pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern#Java)):

```
students.stream()
    .map(student -> Optional.ofNullable(student)
        .filter(s -> s.getId() != null && s.getName() != null)
        .orElse(new NullStudent()))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output would be:

```
Student{id=1, name='a'}
NullStudent{}
Student{id=2, name='b'}
NullStudent{}
Student{id=4, name='d'}
NullStudent{}
Student{id=6, name='f'}
```